# MS ACCESS 97 QUERY

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to do a very simple select sum on orders table but its bringing back count of 82 locations when their is only one location for the first data

```
SELECT Orders.OrderNumber, sum(Orders.Location)
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY  Orders.OrderNumber,Orders.Location
```

[image]

What am I missing in such  a basic query ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the Group By on Location:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderNumber, Sum(Orders.Location) AS SumOfLocation
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Orders.OrderNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need **Orders.Location** in **Group By** Clause

Try this

```
SELECT Orders.OrderNumber, sum(Orders.Location)
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY  Orders.OrderNumber
```